# How to handle multiple actions in Django-Template

Tags: django

I have created a web app in which page which consist of choose file input and Now I need to preprocess the data with one button and that preprocessed data should be used for next button called forecast to show the result in that page.Is it possible with Django. 
Does it compulsory to take any action in page with url changes in django?

Comment: please provide a [mcve] and be specific.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you have a code snippet?

Comment: I want to make changes in html template(input file to be preprocessed and pass to it 
 same page) without changing url

Answer (score 0):

The question is not completely clear, but from what I understand you can use `Ajax`. On first button click send an ajax request, process it in the view logic, send the appropriate data using maybe `JsonResponse`, and in the `success` block of your ajax request set the appropriate data for your forecast button using jquery. Something like -

```
$.ajax({
      url: <url_of_data_processing_logic>,
      type: 'post',
      data: <required data>,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
          $("#<forecast_button_Id>").html(data.forecast_html);
      },
      error: function (e) {
          console.log(e);
      }
    });
```